# Why do we use UserManager to acess user profile info when we can use application dbcontext?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

When I am googling to find how to find `UserProfile` properties I get results and all of them use `UserManager` to access the `UserProfile` custom properties.

So if I have a custom `ApplicationUser`

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public int AccType { get; set; } // 
    }
```

And in my controller a simplified code looks like

```
ApplicationUser usr = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
```

This method exposes the `UserProfile` properties to code. So why is everybody using `UserManager`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UserManager` includes validation rules and helper methods specific to tasks commonly performed for users, like creating a new user with a secure password, verifying an entered password, adding/removing from roles etc.

Yes, you could use `ApplicationDbContext` directly, but you'd need to write queries against your `DbSet<ApplicationUIser>`, when `UserManager` already has these queries already, with validation - and more.

For example, [`UserManager.FindByNameAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/UserManager.cs#L404-L413) is already defined, and additionally it normalizes the name before executing the search.

Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/UserManager.cs) and see what `UserManager` is offering over `DbSet<ApplicationUser>`.